# How do I call this JQuery plugin with a selector?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I found a neat plugin that displays a popup balloon. Seems like it's intended to be triggered by hovering or clicking an a control. I can make this plugin work like this, but I want to be able to call it manually after performing some logic in my code.

The url for this plugin is: http://file.urin.take-uma.net/jquery.balloon.js-Demo.html

The documentation seems to be very limited and all of the examples demonstrate it's use using selectors and hover/click.

Is there a way of calling this plugin conditionally after performing some logic in my code? Sorry... I'm very new to JQuery/Javascript.

Here's how the demo shows its use:

(1) Download and load this plugin javascript file after jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.balloon.js"></script>
```

(2) Call $().balloon(options) in document ready event of jQuery.

```
$(function() {
    $('selectors').balloon(options);
}); 

$('.sample7-2').balloon({
    tipSize: 0, offsetY: -100, offsetX: -100,
    showDuration: 0, hideDuration: 0
});
```

I've made several attempts without success

Comment: What is the second `$()` block for? That's not in the `$.ready()` scope, so it will run as the browser reads it, not after the page loads and the DOM is ready.

Comment: What conditions determine whether or not to execute the balloon call? Replace `$('selectors').balloon(options);` with the code below it. `$('selectors').balloon(options);` is just an example, you don't actually have to execute that specific code. In fact, that code doesn't even do anything because `options` is not defined and `'selectors'` is not a valid jQuery selector..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looked at their code quickly there is a function showBalloon you should invoke when you want the balloon to showup.
They even show you an example

```
$(function() {
  $('#knight').showBalloon({ ... }).toggle(
    function(){ $(this).hideBalloon(); },
    function(){ $(this).showBalloon(); }
 );
```

});

Comment: Making this call: `$().showBalloon({ contents: 'Hello' });` from one of my own functions should load "something", right?

Comment: Yes this would trigger balloon diplay

Comment: Well, that's the code I started with. I can't seem to get anything to display. I'll work with it some more. Thanks!

Comment: you need to use element selector where you want to display the balloon. e.g. $("#somediv").showBalloon({contents: 'Content to display'});

Comment: Yes, I am able to get it to work just by stuffing an arbitrary element selector in the call. Thank you.